# Possible to use a back reference in a number range?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to match a string where a number is equal or higher than a number in a capturing group.

Example:

- `1x1` = match
- `1x2` = match
- `2x1` = no match

In my mind the regex would look something like this `(\d)x[\1-9]` but this doesn't work. Is it possible to achieve this using regex?

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: I am trying to use it in google analytics which I am not sure what flavor it is but I would assume PCPRE

Comment: No, GA uses RE2. That means it is not possible  to do it with a pure regex.

Comment: It would not being possible with pcre as well.

Comment: are you asking if one of the numbers in the string are higher than a threshold or both or their product is?

Comment: @hek2mgl I believe Perl is the only regex syntax that can currently accomplish this in a single regex without post processing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605413/2642059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, you cannot interpolate a value within a regex because:

> Because character classes are determined when the regex is compiled... The only character class regex node type is "hard-coded list of characters" that was built when the regex was compiled (not after it ran part way and figured out what $1 might end up being).

[[Source](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=298163)]

Since character classes do not permit backreferences, a backslash followed by a number is repurposed in a character class:

> A backslash followed by two or three octal digits is considered an octal number.

[[Source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes)]

This obviously isn't what you intended by `[\1-9]`. But since there's no way to compile a character class until all characters are known, we'll have to find another way.

If we're looking to do this entirely within a regex we can't enumerate all possible combinations, because we'd have to check all the captures to figure out which one matched. [For example](https://regex101.com/r/tI4xB7/1):

```
"1x2" =~ m/(?:(0)x(\d)|(1)x([1-9])|(2)x([2-9])|(3)x([3-9])|(4)x([4-9])|(5)x([5-9])|(6)x([6-9])|(7)x([7-9])|(8)x([89])|(9)x(9))/
```

Will contain "1" in `$3` and "2" in `$4`, but you'd have to search captures 1 to 20 to find if anything was matched each time.

---

The only way around doing post processing on regex results is to use a regex conditional: [`(?(A)X)`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html) Where `A` is a conditional and `X` is the resulting action.

[Sadly conditionals are not supported by RE2](https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html), but we'll keep going just to demonstrate it can be done.

What you'd want to use for the `X` is `(*F)` (or `(?!)` in Ruby 2+) to force failure: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.html#fail

What you'd want to use for the `A` is `?{$1 > $2}`, but [**only Perl will allow you to use code directly in a regex**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_code). Perl would allow you to use:

```
m/(\d)x(\d)(?(?{$1 > $2})(?!))/
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Pc7QQn)]

So the answer to your question is: "**No, you cannot do this with RE2 which Google Analytics uses**, but yes you can do this with a Perl regex."